# How do I update Xcode codes I can use iOS 14 functions?

Tags: firebase, ios13, ios14

I was watching a tutorial on how to fetch user location in swift and I had a problem here:

```
class teste: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
@Published var  lctionManager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization (_ manager: CLLocationManagerDelegate){
    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("authorized")
    case .denied:
        print("denied")
    default:
        print("unkown")
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error){
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

The error was a in locationManagerDiChangeAuthorization (Instance method 'locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization' nearly matches optional requirement 'locationManagerDidChangeAuthorizantion' of protocol 'locationManagerDelegate') and in manager.authorizationStatus( Value of type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' has no member 'authoizationStatus')

After some research, I found out that these are iOS 14 only, and my code may be written in iOS13 (actually, for some codes, I have to add @available(iOS 14.0, *) to make them work, but this time it didnt seem it work).
But, as a beginner, I don't know how to update my code (searched for some stuff but nothing caught my eyes). How do I update my code? Would it interfere in anything? Is it necessary or its better to write something to integrate both iOS 14 and 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project -> Info -> iOS Deployment Target

here you can change deployment target to iOS 14.
[image]